# Alternative selection for element with unique ID - python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

[image: k]

There is unique ID that changes for the text field, but the text field is the same!

The id every time looks like this:

> ## id-e9eeb082b846435682bfe4ce10359f17- css
>
> //*[@id="id-e9eeb082b846435682bfe4ce10359f17"] - xpath
> html body div.main.main_bottom-740 div.container div.row div.col-md-24.col-xs-24 div.article-area.article-area_without-top-radius form.step2 div.row div.col-md-12.col-xs-12 input#id-e9eeb082b846435682bfe4ce10359f17.input.input__field.input_full-width.input_with-label-above.input_email-validation - path to CSS

I want to know how to choose it by another way - xpath, or id does not work

Comment: i use the https://docs.katalon.com/display/KR/Overview to get correct selector.

Comment: KAtalon is ok, but i tried to use it

Comment: i even have got the recorded routine in katalon! it still goes by id

Comment: Update the question with relevant text based html

Answer (score 1):

Some HTML in your example could help.

If the ID changes each time you load it you could try something like this:

```
//form[contains(@class,'step2')]/div[contains(@class,'row')]/div[contains(@class,'col-xs-12')]/input[contains(@id,'id-')]
```

Or you might be able to add some form of Regex to it.